# PHP: Pass dynamically created variables to a built-in function

Tags: php, function, variables, dynamic

**DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM:**
What I am trying to do is pass dynamically created variables from a loop to a function in php. More specifically, I used a for loop to create variables and assign data to them. Then use a for loop to string all the variables together. Then pass the string to the multisort_array function and explode the string to use the variables. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

**QUESTION:**
How would I pass a bunch of dynamically created variables to a sort function without knowing how many I am going to create? That is my delema.

**CODE:**

```
$arr2[0] = "100::HOMEDEPOT";
$arr2[1] = "200::WALMART";
$arr2[2] = "300::COSTCO";
$arr2[3] = "400::WALGREENS";
$arr2[4] = "500::TACO BELL";

// explodes first value of $arr2
$tmp = explode("::",$arr2[0]);

// determines how many dynamic variables to create
for($k=0;$k<count($tmp);$k++){
    ${"mArr".$k} = Array();
}

// loops thru & assigns all numbers to mArr0
// loops thru & assigns all names to mArr1
for ($k=0;$k<count($arr2);$k++){
    $tmp = explode("::",$arr2[$k]);

    for($l=0;$l<count($tmp);$l++){
        ${"mArr".$l}[$k] = $tmp[$l];
    }
}

// Will add a for loop to combine the variables into string
$param = "$mArr1,$mArr0";

// send the string to array_multisort to be sorted by name
// have tried the following options:
//   1.   array_multisort(explode(",",$param));
//   2.   call_user_func_array(array_multisort,explode(",",$param));
// both do not sort & give me an error.
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I am open to any suggestions on other ways this can be accomplished, but I would like it to be in the php code if at all possible.

Comment: switch(count($tmp)){
 case 1:
   array_multisort($mArr0);
   break;
 case 2:
   array_multisort($mArr1,$mArr0);
   break;
 case 3:
   array_multisort($mArr1,$mArr0,$mArr2);
   break;
 case 4:
   array_multisort($mArr1,$mArr0,$mArr2,$mArr3);
   break;
 case 5:
   array_multisort($mArr1,$mArr0,$mArr2,$mArr3,$mArr4);
   break;
} echo json_encode($mArr1); // INSTEAD OF DOING THIS I WANTED TO DYNAMICALLY ASSEMBLE A LIST OF DYNAMIC VARIABLES TO PASS.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the array itself into the function.

```
arraySort($array);
```

Comment: what I am trying to do is: array_multisort($mArr1, $mArr0, $mArr2,$mArr3); but I do not know how many of the $mArr## I will have.

Comment: multisort will take a multidimensional arrays. Instead of making a string out of the arrays, load them into another array.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to do? This looks really messy. No offense, but I'm sure there is a much better way to accomplish whatever you're working on.

Comment: I have tried that but what happens is that it sorts the array not the arrays within the array.

Comment: Please refer to the section bolded QUESTION. That is the problem I am trying to work out.

Comment: Then you may consider creating your own function for this purpose. Accept the array, break it into smaller arrays, loop through a for loop and sort those, then package them back into the mother array, and sort that, and return the result.

Comment: In response to your last comment. Sometimes a good programmer will see that he has painted himself into a corner - and the best way to get out of it isn't to go forward with an obviously bad piece of code. But to swallow your pride, realize that nobody makes perfect code, and start over.

Comment: The code is all good. I wanted to get away from writing a switch statement at the bottom to handle the different size variations. But I guess that is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array before splitting it in to other arrays using a [custom sorting function](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
$arr2[0] = "100::HOMEDEPOT";
$arr2[1] = "200::WALMART";
$arr2[2] = "300::COSTCO";
$arr2[3] = "400::WALGREENS";
$arr2[4] = "500::TACO BELL";

//Split the input in place, you could also use a new array for this
for($i = 0;$i < count($arr2);$i++)
{
    $arr2[$i] = explode("::",$arr2[$i]);
}

//Define our new sorting function
function sort_second_item($a,$b)
{
    return strcmp($a[1],$b[1]);
}

var_dump($arr2);
usort($arr2,'sort_second_item');
var_dump($arr2);

$rotated = array();

//Rotate $arr2
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr2); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0;$j < count($arr2[$i]); $j++)
    {
        if(!isset($rotated[$j]))
        {
            $rotated[$j] = array();
        }
        $rotated[$j][$i] = $arr2[$i][$j];
    }
}
var_dump($rotated);
```

Comment: Okay, you changed the question mid answer... not fair.

Comment: The above code will work if the data your always reading in has two arrays. What about reading in data that has two arrays, three arrays, five arrays. How do you handle that? Do you make a function to handle each separately or what I was trying to do was create a function that can handle all of them by dynamically creating variables. The problem I have encountered is how to I send those dynamically created variables to the multisort_array() without know how many I am going to send.